# Why is the catch block not being triggered?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

I am trying to log errors to a file but I can't seem to get the catch block to run when an error occurs. Here is an example of the code:

```
try  
{  
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
}  
catch (MySQLException ex)  
{   
     //run some logging code  
}  
finally  
{  
     //clean up the resources  
}
```

The problem is when there is an exception, I get the error thrown from the built in webserver that its an unhandled exception. When I debug the code stops at the exception then continues on to the finally block. Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: Maybe it's a *different* type of exception than what is asked to be caught?

Comment: Is the exception a `MySQLException`? Or are you trying to do something in the `finally` block that is causing another exception?

Comment: What @pst said. Wrap it in another `try...catch` and check the actual exception while debugging..

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. Indeed as pst suggested when I removed the (MySQLException) it did process the block as a different exception type, in my case System.ArgumentException.

Comment: As a rule - and I truly don't know if this is a 'best practice' - but, when working with something where I am **not** sure of which exception _could be_ thrown, I will have two catch blocks.  One for what I _think_ might get thrown and then `Exception` as my catch-all.

Comment: The better practice would be to have _no_ catch blocks: if you don't know what's being thrown, then don't catch it.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - I suppose that makes sense.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ExecuteNonQuery()` throws an exception of type `SqlException`.

So I'm not sure what `MySQLException` is, but you need to be catching an `SqlException`.

Look at this for extra info:

- [SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx)
- [SqlException Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.aspx).

Comment: -1: thanks for answering, but please don't post .NET 1.1 links in answers. Readers will follow links from that link, etc., and get stuck in .NET 1.1-land.

Comment: Also, what leads you to believe that `cmd` is of type `SqlCommand`?

Comment: I appreciate the correction. I updated the links in my answer. I made an assumption on the type of cmd because he was requesting direction. My direction was to examine the type of Exception that is thrown from the given method.

Comment: Ok, upvoting, but notice how I updated your links: you're better off leaving off the version part if the link without the version exists. Also, it's nice to create a link with the title of the linked article. That way, readers can decide whether or not to click the link.

Comment: Thank you for correcting this, Jeremy.  I have upvoted as well.

Comment: -1. SqlXxxx is for SQL server only. You know, there are other databases and it seems like he is using MySQL. Hence MySqlException. Read here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlexception.html

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the exception thrown is not not of type `MySQLException` or any exception derived from it. So the catch block never never catches it and the finally block is executed directly!

To check what kind of exception was raised, modify the code to:

```
try  
{  
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
}  
catch (MySQLException ex)  
{   
   //run some logging code  
}  
catch (Exception ex)
{
   // any other exception will be handled here
}
finally  
{  
   //clean up the resources  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[That method can throw different types of exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx)

- InvalidCastException
- SqlException
- IOException
- InvalidOperationException
- ObjectDisposedException